# how to send the file with Http request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Please find the below post data for the request to send the file to application,I have tried but not uploading the file to application and even I couldn't see any error for that request in jmeter,Please hel me.

{"requests":[{"event":[{"controller_id":"${codDocID}","event":"AddFileMDSubmit","id":"createFile","param":[{"name":"Path","value":"/Root/AttachmentFolder"},{"name":"Action","value":"CreateFile"}]}],"data":[{"scope":[{"path":"/Root","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/EnableDisableActionMenu","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/$System","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/$ThingHeader","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/UIState","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/ZSchdleDateTime_200486e20a2d29145d81bba1f204e795","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/zFeederRelevant","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/$UISwitch","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/ToCoreBO","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/LaunchPreviewPDFStruct","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/ScopingIndicator","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/HybrisIntegration","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/UtilitiesIndExt","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_ResolutionDueDateTime/content","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_ResolutionDueDateTime","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_CompletionDue/content","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_CompletionDue","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/ExternalSalesOrderDocumentReference","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/EmailFeeder/InteractionAttachments","changed":"","columns":[{"path":"SelectedIndicator","changed":"X"},{"path":"NodeID","changed":"X"}]},{"path":"/Root/Customer_BusinessPartner/Structure","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/Customer_BusinessPartner","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/PricingTerms","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/CpTotalCustAmount_0479727343a243b5b39e3b8dd38054aa","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/CpTotalReclAmount_bff3d7be2aec457786179c6bc6f0e83b","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/CpTotalReclUponRet_55e401c0e848418fb07a3b71c480125e","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/CpTotalCustInDest_ebcecb07263e4d81b8ad6a2105b4ce16","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/CpTotalReclInDest_73eb1b917ee34f2db12f1d491d0e642e","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/CpTotalCustUponRet_4d69521c51ac4e7b96601ad2402a599e","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/ZK_ApprovedAmount_75f8a8768f4708ab080050e720617a13","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/CreatedOn","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/ChangedOn","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_InitialReceipt/content","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_InitialReceipt","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_InitialResponseDue/content","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_InitialResponseDue","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_InitialResponse/content","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_InitialResponse","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_Completion/content","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_Completion","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_ResponseByProcessorDue/content","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_ResponseByProcessorDue","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/CpApprovalAchievedDateTime_e5a9db72014e12473aa7b19f1b100ecc","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/SearchResults","changed":"","columns":[{"path":"Index","changed":"X"},{"path":"ArticleIcon","changed":"X"},{"path":"ExternalKnowledgeBaseArticleURI","changed":"X"},{"path":"ExternalKnowledgeBaseCode","changed":"X"},{"path":"ExternalKnowledgeBaseArticleID","changed":"X"},{"path":"Author","changed":"X"},{"path":"Date","changed":"X"},{"path":"ExternalKnowledgeBaseArticleDescription","changed":"X"},{"path":"ExternalKnowledgeBaseArticleDescription1","changed":"X"},{"path":"ExternalKnowledgeBaseArticleShortURI","changed":"X"},{"path":"ExternalKnowledgeBaseArticleURI1","changed":"X"},{"path":"JAMUri","changed":"X"},{"path":"JAMViewsCount","changed":"X"},{"path":"NodeID","changed":"X"},{"path":"Note","changed":"X"}]},{"path":"/Root/From_KB_EC/DetailView","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/From_KB_EC","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/SimilarTickets","changed":"","columns":[{"path":"Index","changed":"X"},{"path":"Name","changed":"X"},{"path":"ID","changed":"X"},{"path":"UUID","changed":"X"},{"path":"@RowCount","changed":"X"},{"path":"CustomerFormattedName","changed":"X"},{"path":"ReporterName","changed":"X"},{"path":"ServiceRequestUserLifeCycleStatusCode","changed":"X"},{"path":"CreationDateTime","changed":"X"},{"path":"ProductID","changed":"X"}]},{"path":"/Root/SimilarTicket_UIData","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TimeEntry_MergeTimeItem","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/ChildServiceRequstModificationUserSelected","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_ResolvedOnDateTime","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_OnSiteArrivalDateTime","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_OnSiteArrivalDueDateTime","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_RequestedFulfillmentEndDateTime","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_RequestedFulfillmentStartDateTime","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_Escalation","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_ResponseByCustomer","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/TP_ResponseByProcessor","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/WarrantyReferenceDateTime","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/StickyNoteInteractor","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/PricingTerms/DateTime","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/Groups_Recommended","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/LoggedUserDetails","changed":""},{"path":"/Root/zAWS_Features","changed":""}],"id":"${codSeodAgentID}"},{"id":"${codDocID}","flat_data":[{"key_path":"/Root/AttachmentFolder/AddParams/TypeCode","value":"${typeCodeVal}","aspect":"C"},{"key_path":"/Root/AttachmentFolder/OutputRelevant","value":"","aspect":"C"},{"key_path":"/Root/AttachmentFolder/AddParams/fileName","value":"${fileName}","aspect":"C"},{"key_path":"/Root/AttachmentFolder/AddParams/Title","value":"${fileName}","aspect":"C"},{"key_path":"/Root/AttachmentFolder/AddParams/fileSize","value":"190","aspect":"C"},{"key_path":"/Root/AttachmentFolder/AddParams/content","value":"id%3D00163E2F045E1EE88BD561E26708DE0E","aspect":"C"}]}]}]}

Comment: in place of file name i have used the variable name ${fileName},as it's having the value as name of the file

Answer (score 0):

1. Store your file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation as i.e. `data.json`
2. Switch to "File Upload" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter File Upload]

If you're uncertain regarding what to put in the "Parameter Name" field you can just record your request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) via web browser, just make sure that the `data.json` file is present in JMeter's "bin" folder. Check out [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: @Dmirti-The content which I posted above is the post data for that request,the following is the parameter name for the file name.                                       "key_path":"/Root/AttachmentFolder/AddParams/fileName","value":"${fileName}"